# Last.FM how to get a song to play

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I want to develop an Android app that plays music from Last.FM API.

But I can’t find methods that response with mp3 file. Also in Last.FM API documentation I couldn’t find the answer! I can retrieve only track/artist/charts and etc. But I need track media file…to play selected track.

I need to play music without user authentication is it possible?

Does someone know how I can retrieve Last.FM song to play (which method will allow to to it and give me the media file? Or maybe there is some other solution, maybe documentation/example?)

Comment: That api doesn't have that method so there is nothing you can do about it. Research for another api.

Answer (score 0):

lastfm does not provide media file that contain .mp3 file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).